# Why is there ambiguous route message in Blazor SPA?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-server-side

8/25/2020
I am working through an e-commerce example out of a book and the majority of the ASP.Net 3.1 Web App is in MVC.  There are some simple pages where Razor Pages are used.  And finally in administration we are using Blazor.
In setting up the routes in Startup.Configure() we have:

```
           // MVC default endpoint
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            // RazorPages endpoints
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            // Blazor endpoints
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            //   Map requests to SPA (Blazor)
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/admin/{*catchall}", 
            "/Admin/Index");
```

So I am thinking "/admin/{*catchall} would catch the following URLs (off of the base URL of course).

1. /admin
2. /admin/orders
3. /admin/products

Since Razor Pages are used to host a Blazor app, the Fallback when you go to /admin is really directed to /Pages/Admin/Index.cshtml which has this host file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SportsStore Admin</title>
    <link href="/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(Routed)" render-mode="Server" />
    <script src="/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

which loads the Routed Component:

```
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Startup).Assembly">
    <Found>
        <RouteView RouteData="@context" DefaultLayout="typeof(AdminLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <h4 class="bg-danger text-white text-center p-2">
            No Matching Route
        </h4>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

This loads the AdminLayout Component:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="bg-info text-white p-2">
    <span class="navbar ml-2">SPORTS STORE Administration</span>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row p-2">
        <div class="col-3">
            <NavLink class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block"
                     href="/admin/products"
                     ActiveClass="btn-primary text-white"
                     Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                Products
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block"
                     href="/admin/orders"
                     ActiveClass="btn-primary text-white"
                     Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                Orders
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see in the AdminLayout two NavLinks which work fine.
And here are the top of the two files they link to.

a) /Pages//admin/orders.razor:

```
@page "/admin/orders"
@inherits OwningComponentBase<IOrderRepository>
```

b) /Pages/admin/products.razor

```
@page "/admin/products"
@page "/admin"
```

This is what all the routes look like at this point:

1. /admin: Typing URL directly in

[image]

You can see there is no active state on the Products button even though I am there I guess because it is specified on a NavLink taghelper in the layout and must be clicked to get the ActiveClass applied.
But the route is found.

2. Now if I click products this is what renders:
   [image]

So both /admin and /admin/products get me there.
By clicking the NavLink button the active state is applied to the Products NavLink button.

These two URLs get me there because of the two routes specified in the Products component:

```
@page "/admin/products"
@page "/admin"
```

3. If I click the Orders NavLinkButton:

[image]

Orders ActiveState is applied from clicking the Orders NavLink button and matching this route at the top of the orders component:

```
@page "/admin/orders"
```

But now when I manually enter
/admin/products
or
/admin/orders

I get ambiguous route error message:

[image]

and for /admin/orders the same thing.

If I comment out the /admin route in Products.razor I get the NoRouteFound response from the Routed.razor file:

```
@page "/admin/products"
@*@page "/admin"*@
```

[image]

So routing has always been confusing to me.
I think what is happening is the catch all in startup:

```
//   Map requests to SPA (Blazor)
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/admin/{*catchall}", 
"/Admin/Index");
```

### goes to the Index.cshtml Razor page as the host of the SPA app and initializes the Blazor app.  From here on out there is a persistant HTTP connection to the Server (a little different from the likes of Angular) and routing now is handled by the Blazor app until the user clicks on or manually enters an endpoint registered before the Blazor endpoints in StartUp.  So is this typical in an SPA or is there a way to make manual URL entries work.  This may be cleared up as I work through the chapter but I am always fuzzy on routing in all of my technologies.

8/26/2020 - Update

Now when working in the products or orders components, every time I make a change, even a small HTML change, the browser says "reloading", and when I click reload or refresh, I get the ambiguous router thing again, so I am having to clean and rebuild after every little change to see the rendering in the browser.  This is very annoying.
Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the route to the hosting Index.cshtml razor page:

```
@page "/admin"
```

Everything seems to work now.